# How to delete json files if they contain a specific key/value

Tags: python, json

I have a directory of json files. I want to delete the files that have this in them.

```
{
    "error": "not_found",
    "message": "Can't find",
    "value": "item"
}
```

This is 2 versions of what I have now. The error says "string indices must be integers" so I think how I'm writing the syntax wrong. But I can't find the syntax for how to select if the key/value = x

```
for file in fileList:
    with open(filepath) as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
    data2 = [file for file in data if file['error'] == 'not_found']
    os.remove("filepath")
```

I also did this instead and I think a if statement should work

```
for file in fileList:
    my_json_dict = json.loads(file)
    if file for file in my_json_dict if file.get('error', True):
        os.remove("filepath")
```

Comment: Do you want to to remove files that have _exactly_ those three values?  What if the file has those three values, plus other values?

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you are doing:

```py
file for file in data
```

`file` is a `str`, because it's each key in the dictionary `data`.

```py
# over a sample dictionary
data = {'here': None, 'is': None, 'content': None}

for k in data:
    print(k, type(k))

# prints each key and the type 'str'
here <class 'str'>
is <class 'str'>
content <class 'str'>
```

And `str` only supports integer indexing:

```py
'here'['hello']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Instead do:

```py
for filepath in test:
    with open(filepath) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
   
    # test against the file itself
    found = data.get('error') == 'not_found'

    if found:
        os.remove(filepath)
```

## Edit

To match *all* of the fields indicated:

```py
fields = {
    "error": "not_found",
    "message": "Can't find",
    "value": "item"
}

for filepath in test:
    with open(filepath) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    found = all(data.get(k) == v for k, v in fields.items())

    if found:
        os.remove(filepath)
```

And if you want the data in the file to be *exactly* fields (not a superset):

```py
fields = {
    "error": "not_found",
    "message": "Can't find",
    "value": "item"
}

for filepath in test:
    with open(filepath) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    # the contents must be exactly alike
    if data == fields:
        os.remove(filepath)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I saw the brackets in so many examples but I knew it didn't make sense. I appreciate your time